# <a4j:commandButton> is not invoking the action method

Tags: jsf-2

I am new to JSF and I am doing an enhancement project. I added one `a4j: comandButton` and while I was trying to call the action method specified inside controller class, I am not getting any result. Instead of the newly created method I was trying to put an old action method and it was working perfectly. I am not sure what mistake I am doing or what the things need to be added.

```html
<a4j:commandButton` id= "data"  value="Data"
        styleClass="normalButton"
        action = "#{controller.dataReset}"
        status="waitStatus" oncomplete="clearDirtyFlag();">
</a4j:commandButton>
```

Comment: So why don't you compare the old working method with the new none working method?

Comment: Thank you for your answer . i just compared with old working method with new one ,i dont see any difference and all over that i am just calling a simple action method with println for testing purpose . it is not showing any error also in log